# each time printing result set in data of 3

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ecmascript-6, iteration

- I am trying to print the data in chunks of three.
- so I thought I will iterate the array and each time I will take three elements and print it.
- so I thought I will use slice but not working
- but I am not sure how to proceed.
- providing my code snippet below.
- I debugged but still not sure how to proceed.

```or-tag-here
let array = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 78, 3, 999, 544, 3, 3, 32233, 223, ];
array.map(search => {
  //  return {
  console.log("chunks of data--->", search.slice(3));
  //     };
});
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only want to print everything once, if that is the case you have to use %3 to do something every 3x time - in this case logging the current and past 2 elements. at the end you also have to print the left over elements in case your number of elements isnt a multiple of 3.

```
// a forEach loop takes an array and calls a function on each element in it
array.forEach((el, index, arr) => {
    // is this element a multiple of 3?
    if ((index + 1) % 3 === 0) {
        // If so, log it, as well as the 2 preceding elements
        console.log(arr[index-2], arr[index-1], el)

    // Otherwise, is this element the last one in the array, meaning there
    // wont be another tuple logging this element
    } else if (index === arr.length - 1) {
        // If so, how many elements are left, one or two?
        // log this many last elements to the console
        // I used a ternary in this case it is basically a shorthand if 
        // [expression] ? [if true] : [if false]
        arr.length % 3 === 1 ? console.log(arr[index]) : console.log(arr[index - 1], arr[index])
    }
})
```

Comment: hey thanks, it worked but can you give comments. I am not able to understand this line `arr.length % 3 === 1 ? console.log(arr[index]) : console.log(arr[index - 1], arr[index])` so that I can learn

Answer (score 0):

You must use `index` for this

```js
let array = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 78, 3, 999, 544, 3, 3, 32233, 223, ];
array.map((search,index) => {

  if(index%3!==0){
     return;
  }

  let limit = index+3;
  
  // this part need when index almost at the end of the array
  if((index+3)>=array.length){
     limit =array.length;
  }
  console.log("chunks of data--->", array.slice(index,limit));
  //     };
});
```

Comment: hey thanks, it worked but can you give comments. I am not able to understand this line `const limit = (index+3)>=array.length?array.length:index+3;` so that I can learn

Comment: @tkkk i little change my code, now must be ease for understanst

Comment: hey if I remove the below if condition also its working fine and why I am not see the space character in the end ` if((index+3)>=array.length){
     limit =array.length;
  }`

Comment: can you give me some more detailed explanation

Comment: @tkkk, without condition it's work not correctly `1 4 5` and `4 5 6` contain inside same elements. So about details, i dont see a hard moments for understand, just operators `+ - = < >` and `conditions`. Which part it hard understand for you?

Comment: why I am not see the space character in the end

Answer (score 0):

You use `slice` with an array, not a number, to get chunks of `3` (or any arbitrary `n`), use this:

```js
var array = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 78, 3, 999, 544, 3, 3, 32233, 223, ];

var n = 3;
var chunk;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += n) {
  chunk = array.slice(i, i + n);
  console.log(chunk);
}
```

Comment: hey thanks, it worked but can you give comments. I am not able to understand this line `var i = 0; i < array.length; i += n)` so that I can learn